# Cloud function: HTTP trigger inconsistent batch commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update multiple collections in my Firestore and RTDB by triggering Google cloud function through an HTTP request, and I've done some several times of testing, but the batch commit works **from time to time**. I've also tried running test excluding RTDB update from the code, but nothing changes much.

*If something goes wrong, I get the following error message with status code 500*.

> Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.

Here's the example code:

**Server-side code**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = ({ admin, cors, express, functions }) => {
  const app = express();
  const fireStore = admin.firestore();
  const rtdb = admin.database();
  const apps = fireStore.collection('apps');
  const users = fireStore.collection('users');
  const batch = admin.firestore().batch();

  app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

  ...

  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const uid = req.user.user_id;
    const data = req.body;
    const appsRef = apps.doc(uid);
    const usersRef = users.doc(uid);

    const activityState = {
      currentActiveStatus: data.activityState.currentActiveStatus,
      usingApp: data.activityState.usingApp
    };

    const appState = {
      emailVerified: data.user.emailVerified
    };

    const userState = {
      displayName: data.user.displayName,
      photoURL: data.user.photoURL,
      currentActiveStatus: data.user.currentActiveStatus,
      lastLoginAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    };

    batch.update(appsRef, appState);
    batch.update(usersRef, userState);

    return batch.commit().then(() => {
      console.log('Batch commit finished!');
      return admin.database().ref(`status/${uid}`).update(activityState).then(() => {
      res.status(201).send({ message: 'Successfully Initialize Default State' });
      });
    }).catch(err => console.log('Err:', err));
  });

  return functions.https.onRequest(app);
};
```

**Client-side code**

```
const data = {
      activityState: {
        currentActiveStatus: "online",
        usingApp: "true"
      },
      user: {
        displayName: this.displayName,
        photoURL: this.photoURL,
        currentActiveStatus: "online",
        emailVerified: "true"
      }
    };
    this.userService.updateUserProfile(this.displayName, this.photoURL).then((accessToken) => {
      const url = 'https://us-central1/dbname/cloudfunctions.net/functionname';
      this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: {'Authorization': accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
      }).subscribe((res) => {
        // Worked well
      }, (err) => {
        // Went wrong
      });
    });
```

**Error message in details**

```
Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.  
    at WriteBatch.verifyNotCommitted (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:148:13)  
    at WriteBatch.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:333:10)  
    at app.post (/user_code/exports/auth/user/startapp/initDefaultState.f.js:54:11)  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)  
    at next (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)  
    at Route.dispatch (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)  
    at /user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22  
    at Function.process_params (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)  
    at next (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Perhaps I'm missing something out in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. It was a silly mistake that I've made.

I had to declare batch inside `app.post()`.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
});
```

Instead

```
module.exports = ({ admin, cors, express, functions }) => {
  const app = express();
  const fireStore = admin.firestore();
  const rtdb = admin.database();
  const apps = fireStore.collection('apps');
  const users = fireStore.collection('users');
  const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
};
```

Comment: Maybe creating the `batch` object inside the post would suffice? Otherwise everytime a __post__ to `/` happens, you'll create the `admin`, the `db`, the batch, etc...